# Visual Studio Cordova Android Emulator or Device Debug Build Fail

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, build, android-emulator

When I compile to Ripple the App appears, yet when I try the emulator or device I get a failed build with output as follows.

All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
NuGet package restore finished.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FrozenWolf, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>
1>  C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf>"C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd"   build --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName FrozenWolf --npmInstallDir C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\npm --language en-US --buildTarget AndroidEmulator
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.0.0 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: FrozenWolf
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\native\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins:
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
1>  Preparing android project
1>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
1>  Iterating over installed plugins: []
1>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "FrozenWolf"
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myapp407c855b15dd4d1fb09c19142947bc01"
1>  ------ Copied C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
1>  ------ Building platform: android
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug --ant ""
1>  Command finished with error code 2: cmd /s /c ""C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FrozenWolf\FrozenWolf\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug --ant "
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is Apache Ant in your path?

Comment: System Variables-   
  
Variable Name: ANT_HOME  
Variable Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio  14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3  
  
Path: %Path%;%ANT_HOME%\bin;

Comment: You will also need to add the JDK and Android SDK to your path as described here: [Configure the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx)